# How do I spawn Oshabi?

Tags: path-of-exile

It's not exactly clear what I have to do to spawn Oshabi for the Harvest league challenge.  Especially considering I've completed all of the quests and there is nothing else indicating what I need to do to Harvest the Heart of the Grove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to complete two step to unlock the fight:

1. Grow a T4 seed of any colour and kill the mob it spawns.
2. Open 100 Seed Caches in Red maps. ( T10+ )
3. Fight Oshabi!